# How to generate jacoco.exec file with Gradle for Espresso Automation Test

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I am running automation test cases using espresso. HTML reports are generated but .exec file is not generated. I want .exec file to be generated which can be used for sonar. Please help.